# Eslint vue lint html element line break

Tags: vue.js, eslint, lint

Is there a way to use eslint Vue to lint line breaks like so?

```
<!--GOOD-->
<div>data 1<div>

<div>
    <div>data 2<div>

    <div>data 3<div>
<div>

<div>data 4<div>

<!--BAD-->
<div>data 1<div>
<div>
    <div>data 2<div>
    <div>data 3<div>
<div>
<div>data 4<div>
```

Basically give spaces between html elements.

tks

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Comment: No I haven't sadly.